# jQuery Datepicker doesnt display events on first 10 days of each month

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Got a problem with jquery datepicker. Everything is working as expected but the events from the first 10 days of each month doesnt show up. Classes are not applying even that the dates for those days are loaded to the script.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oug2T.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0d5b.png

I have tried multiple codes including setting minDate and maxDate and none of those worked.

````
        var dates = [['2019-09-01', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-02', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-03', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-04', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-05', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-06', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-07', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-08', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-09', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-10', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-11', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-12', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-13', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-14', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-15', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-16', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-17', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-18', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-19', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-20', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-21', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-22', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-23', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-24', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-25', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-26', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-27', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-28', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-29', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-09-30', 'ui-highlight1'],['2019-10-01', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-02', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-03', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-04', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-05', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-06', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-07', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-08', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-09', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-10', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-11', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-12', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-13', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-14', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-15', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-16', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-17', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-18', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-19', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-20', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-21', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-22', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-23', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-24', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-25', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-26', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-27', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-28', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-29', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-30', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-10-31', 'ui-highlight10'],['2019-11-01', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-02', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-03', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-04', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-05', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-06', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-07', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-08', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-09', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-10', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-11', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-12', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-13', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-14', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-15', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-16', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-17', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-18', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-19', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-20', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-21', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-22', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-23', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-24', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-25', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-26', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-27', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-28', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-29', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-11-30', 'ui-highlight3'],['2019-12-01', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-02', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-03', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-04', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-05', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-06', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-07', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-08', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-09', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-10', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-11', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-12', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-13', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-14', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-15', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-16', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-17', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-18', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-19', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-20', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-21', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-22', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-23', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-24', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-25', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-26', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-27', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-28', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-29', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-30', 'ui-highlight5'],['2019-12-31', 'ui-highlight5'],['2020-01-01', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-02', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-03', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-04', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-05', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-06', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-07', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-08', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-09', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-10', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-11', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-12', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-13', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-14', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-15', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-16', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-17', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-18', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-19', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-20', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-21', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-22', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-23', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-24', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-25', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-26', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-27', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-28', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-29', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-30', 'ui-highlight9'],['2020-01-31', 'ui-highlight9'],];
        var ids = ['9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9','9',];
        jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
                changeMonth : true,
                changeYear : true,

                beforeShowDay : function SetDayStyle(date) {
                                var maxDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 16, 11, 31);
    var enabled = true;
    var cssClass = "";
    var toolTip = "";

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1; //0 - 11
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var compare = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        //var toolTip = dates[i].indexOf(compare) + " " + compare
        if (dates[i].indexOf(compare) >= 0) cssClass = dates[i][1];
    }

    return new Array(enabled, cssClass, toolTip);
}

            });
            $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate",'');
            $("#datepicker")
    .datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $(this).change();
      }
    })
    .change(function() {
      window.location.href = "page.php?op=stocktake&cmd=stock_slist&sid=&sdate=" + this.value;
    });

        })
    </script>```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnFVi.png
````

Comment: Instead of the screenshots. Could you post you code here for better understanding

Comment: `var maxDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 16` shouldn't that be `+16` ?

Comment: Does it work if you take you the `beforeShowDay` code?  ie is it your code that's breaking it or something else?

Comment: @Gulshan the only other code is a simple div with datepicker id what code you are reffering to?

Comment: @freedomn-m
Ad.1 changing minus to plus makes no difference.
Ad 2. datepicker doesnt load once removed beforeShowDay code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add some basic debugging:

```
console.log(compare, enabled, cssClass, toolTip)
```

you'll see that your `compare` date doesn't match the format of the dates in your date array:

```
 "2019-11-1" != "2019-11-02"
```

```js
var dates = [

  ['2019-10-21', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-22', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-23', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-24', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-25', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-26', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-27', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-28', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-29', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-30', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-31', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-11-01', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-02', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-03', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-04', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-05', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-06', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-07', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-08', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-09', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-10', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-11', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-12', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-13', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-14', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-15', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-16', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-17', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-18', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-19', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-20', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-21', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-22', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-23', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-24', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-25', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-26', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-27', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-28', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-29', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-30', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-12-01', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-02', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-03', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-04', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-05', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-06', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-07', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-08', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-09', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-10', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-11', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-12', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-13', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-14', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-15', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-16', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-17', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-18', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-19', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-20', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-21', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-22', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-23', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-24', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-25', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-26', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-27', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-28', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-29', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-30', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-31', 'ui-highlight5'],
];
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,

    beforeShowDay: function SetDayStyle(date) {
      var maxDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 16, 11, 31);
      var enabled = true;
      var cssClass = "";
      var toolTip = "";

      var day = date.getDate();
      var month = date.getMonth() + 1; //0 - 11
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var compare = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

      for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        //var toolTip = dates[i].indexOf(compare) + " " + compare
        if (dates[i].indexOf(compare) >= 0) cssClass = dates[i][1];
      }

      console.log(compare, enabled, cssClass, toolTip)
      return new Array(enabled, cssClass, toolTip);
    }

  });
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", '');
  $("#datepicker")
    .datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $(this).change();
      }
    })
    .change(function() {
      console.log(this.value);
      //window.location.href = "page.php?op=stocktake&cmd=stock_slist&sid=&sdate=" + this.value;
    });

})
```

```css
.ui-highlight3 
{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type='date' id='datepicker'>
```

You need to either format your dates so they match, or compare as dates:

```
var compare = year + "-" + ("0"+month).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0"+day).slice(-2);
```

```js
var dates = [

  ['2019-10-21', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-22', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-23', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-24', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-25', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-26', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-27', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-28', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-29', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-30', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-10-31', 'ui-highlight10'],
  ['2019-11-01', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-02', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-03', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-04', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-05', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-06', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-07', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-08', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-09', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-10', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-11', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-12', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-13', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-14', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-15', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-16', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-17', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-18', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-19', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-20', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-21', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-22', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-23', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-24', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-25', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-26', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-27', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-28', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-29', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-11-30', 'ui-highlight3'],
  ['2019-12-01', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-02', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-03', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-04', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-05', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-06', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-07', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-08', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-09', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-10', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-11', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-12', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-13', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-14', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-15', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-16', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-17', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-18', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-19', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-20', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-21', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-22', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-23', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-24', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-25', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-26', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-27', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-28', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-29', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-30', 'ui-highlight5'],
  ['2019-12-31', 'ui-highlight5'],
];
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,

    beforeShowDay: function SetDayStyle(date) {
      // never used: var maxDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear() - 16, 11, 31);
      var enabled = true;
      var cssClass = "";
      var toolTip = "";

      var day = date.getDate();
      var month = date.getMonth() + 1; //0 - 11
      var year = date.getFullYear();
      var compare = year + "-" + ("0"+month).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0"+day).slice(-2);

      for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        //var toolTip = dates[i].indexOf(compare) + " " + compare
        if (dates[i].indexOf(compare) >= 0) cssClass = dates[i][1];
      }

      console.log(compare, enabled, cssClass, toolTip)
      return new Array(enabled, cssClass, toolTip);
    }

  });
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", '');
  $("#datepicker")
    .datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $(this).change();
      }
    })
    .change(function() {
      console.log(this.value);
      //window.location.href = "page.php?op=stocktake&cmd=stock_slist&sid=&sdate=" + this.value;
    });

})
```

```css
.ui-highlight3 
{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type='date' id='datepicker'>
```

Comment: ```var compare = year + "-" + ("0"+month).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0"+day).slice(-2);``` did the trick. Thank you